# Need to export the XML file data to excel file

Tags: powershell

I have XML File. I want to export some data from XML File to excel file using vbscript or powershell. here the sample XML file. I need to export only the param data contains in below given xml data

[image: XML File]

Comment: So, what happened when you tried to do that? What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: I tried with different script files using power shell and vbscript. I am getting error or no output

Comment: SO is not a coding service, so you need to add your best attempt, and the error you're getting. Otherwise it's pretty impossible to guess what's wrong with your code.

Comment: $XMLfile = 'e:\events.xml'
[XML]$Events = Get-Content $XMLfile

foreach($Events1 in $Events.Events.UserData){
 
Write-Host "Employee Id :" $Events1.Param1
#Write-Host "Employee mail Id :" $Events1.mailId
#Write-Host "Employee Name :" $Events1.empName
Write-Host ''
 
}
           the script i had tried but Nothing happened while executed the script

Comment: I tried this command also ===    Select-Xml -Path e:\events.xml -XPath '/Events/UserData' | ForEach-Object { $_.Node.Parm1 }

Comment: [Edit] the question and put Powershell code there. It is hard to read code from comments, and those are ephemeral anyway. There is no syntax highlighting, nor line breaks. SO is not a discussion board, so don't try to use comments as such.

Comment: @Arunkumar the Xpath paramters of the Select-Xml function is wrong. If you want to query each event Xml element you should use as Xpath **/Events/Event**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this [forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a439492-56b6-48df-aba7-f19124b77cd8/powershell-getwinevent-xml-extended-providers) showing an answer to a quite similar question.

This solution assumes you can use PowerShell to retrieve the data.

```
# specify filter for events to retrieve
$filter = @{
    LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational'
    ID=307
}

# retrieve events and convert to xml
[xml[]]$xml = Get-WinEvent -filterHashTable $filter | %{$_.ToXml()}

# extract events from xml
$events = $xml | Select-Xml '//x:Event' -Namespace @{ x = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node

# convert "Param*" nodes to CSV
$events | %{$_.UserData.DocumentPrinted} | select Param* | Export-Csv C:\path\to\307-events.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This results all "Param*" nodes into the specified file which then can be opened in Excel.

Comment: Thanks the above script working perfectly what I excepted. Thanks to all members (Personally thanks to Guenther Schmitz)